# How does bitcore-node get its data?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcore, bitpay

I'm trying to understand how does [bitcore-node](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node), the javascript implementation of Bitcoin protocol, get its data? Can it connect to Bitcoin Core, the original C++ implementation of the Bitcoin protocol, or does it have to connect to other bitcore-nodes ?

Answer (score 3):

> A Bitcoin blockchain indexing and query service. Intended to be used with as a Bitcoin full node or in conjunction with a Bitcoin full node.

From the first line of the README. It’s an out of date wrapper on Bitcoin that’s 3 years old at this point and would be inadvisable to use for anything.